# Why does my Codename One build fail with a StackOverflowError?

Tags: build, java-me, codenameone

I'm trying to build my application for J2ME using the Codename One build server.  This has been working fine, but now I get a build error every time.  Here's an extract from the log, which mentions a StackOoverflowError while preparing the output jar:

```
Preparing output jar [/tmp/build8143824389622734358xxx/result/MyApplication.jar]
Copying resources from program directory [/tmp/build8143824389622734358xxx/tmpclasses]
Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
com.codename1.build.daemon.Executor.unzip(Executor.java:904)
com.codename1.build.daemon.Executor.unzip(Executor.java:904)
com.codename1.build.daemon.Executor.unzip(Executor.java:904)
com.codename1.build.daemon.Executor.unzip(Executor.java:904)
com.codename1.build.daemon.Executor.unzip(Executor.java:904)
com.codename1.build.daemon.Executor.unzip(Executor.java:904)
```

That last line then repeats another 1023 times, all the way to the end of the file.

I've rewound my source to a version that I have built before and that now fails too, with the same error message.

Could this be something that's changed in my development environment, or is this an issue with the build server?

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks a lot,

Paul

Comment: It calls recursivly `com.codename1.build.daemon.Executor.unzip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a temporary issue with some iOS builds. It was resolved in an hour.